# How to move the time cursor with the mouse in python?

Tags: python, video-sequence-editor

I'm trying to create mouse-based cut and trim functions for the VSE, to allow for fast edits when scrubbing the timeline. Using Ctrl Right Mouse as a keyboard shortcut, Blender handles the strip's selection with the Right Mouse button, and then triggers the operator.

The problem is that I can't find a way to move the time cursor where the user clicks from a Python script. I looked into the reference API, and in Blender's python console, I also set:

```
bpy.app.debug_wm = True
```

To no success. Nothing shows up in the console when you left click in the VSE. And I looked up online, couldn't find an answer.

So, do you know how I could set the current frame/place the time cursor based on where the mouse is from a python operator?

Kind regards,
Nathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an adjustment of the answer to this q [Getting area (region.view2d) pixel coordinates of 2D views (VSE, NLA)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38681/getting-area-region-view2d-pixel-coordinates-of-2d-views-vse-nla)

Run the script, use the spacebar to search out the "Simple Modal Sequencer Operator" and the current frame will change with the mouse.

The key method is `region.view2d.region_to_view` which returns, in this case, the frame in x and the strip channel in y, from the regions pixel coords.

```
import bpy
import bgl
import blf


def draw_callback_px(self, context):
    print("mouse points", len(self.mouse_path))

    region = context.region
    strip = context.scene.sequence_editor.active_strip
    if strip is None:
        return

    x = strip.frame_final_start
    y = strip.channel
    x, y = region.view2d.view_to_region(x, y)
    font_id = 0  # XXX, need to find out how best to get this.

    # draw some text
    blf.position(font_id, x, y, 0)
    blf.size(font_id, 20, 72)
    # region_to_view gives the region coords.  x is frame, y is channel.
    x, y = region.view2d.region_to_view(*self.mouse_path[-1] )
    blf.draw(font_id, "Hello Word %d %d" % (x, y))
    # move the frame to the mouse
    context.scene.frame_set(x)


class ModalDrawOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Draw a line with the mouse"""
    bl_idname = "sequencer.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Modal Sequencer Operator"

    def modal(self, context, event):
        context.area.tag_redraw()
        region = context.region

        if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':
            self.mouse_path.append((event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y))

        elif event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':
            bpy.types.SpaceSequenceEditor.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
            return {'FINISHED'}

        elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            bpy.types.SpaceSequenceEditor.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        if context.area.type == 'SEQUENCE_EDITOR':
            # the arguments we pass the the callback
            args = (self, context)
            # Add the region OpenGL drawing callback
            # draw in view space with 'POST_VIEW' and 'PRE_VIEW'
            self._handle = bpy.types.SpaceSequenceEditor.draw_handler_add(draw_callback_px, args, 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')

            self.mouse_path = []

            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "SequenceEditor not found, cannot run operator")
            return {'CANCELLED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalDrawOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalDrawOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

PS I slapped this together pretty quickly and put code in the draw hander rather than the event loop of the operator. Will fix later...

Comment: This is super duper cool! It actually solves multiple questions I had at once (how to make this tool modal, and how to print info on the screen). Thanks a lot! :)