# New Keyframe Types

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline

On version 2.78 there are new keyframe types available on the timeline.

> Jitter
>
> Extreme
>
> Breakdown
>
> Keyframe

Can someone please explain how they are used?
[image]

Are they only colors that display on the dopesheet with no other funcionalty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are only for visual distinguish regular keyframes from different animation events or states.Besides I would swear they were there earlier (just can't find them in 2.77). Although I found conversation on the topic from 2009 so it's definitely not a new feature. Check the manual for [more info](https://www.blender.org/manual/fr/animation/keyframes/introduction.html#keyframe-types)

Comment: New as in "New Keyframe Type"

Comment: The answer still stands though. It still is only for visual distinguish keyframes :)

Comment: They are not new. Just the location is new. And it's a double menu entry now. The original menu can for example be found in the Dope Sheet editor in Key / Keyframe Type.